# Apache mod_rewrite vulnerability

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities

The public exploits of apache mod_rewrite asks for the rewrite path in order to work, and I am unsure what the rewrite path is referring to. What should I supply in rewrite path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to read the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which explains how rewrite works. From that page:

> **Summary** The mod_rewrite module uses a rule-based rewriting engine,
>   based on a PCRE regular-expression parser, to rewrite requested URLs
>   on the fly. By default, mod_rewrite maps a URL to a filesystem path.
>   However, it can also be used to redirect one URL to another URL, or to
>   invoke an internal proxy fetch.
>
> mod_rewrite provides a flexible and powerful way to manipulate URLs
>   using an unlimited number of rules. Each rule can have an unlimited
>   number of attached rule conditions, to allow you to rewrite URL based
>   on server variables, environment variables, HTTP headers, or time
>   stamps.
>
> mod_rewrite operates on the full URL path, including the path-info
>   section. A rewrite rule can be invoked in httpd.conf or in .htaccess.
>   The path generated by a rewrite rule can include a query string, or
>   can lead to internal sub-processing, external request redirection, or
>   internal proxy throughput.

So the path is whatever you want it to be.